# Cannot resolve method 'get(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, android

How can I fetch position for row in recyclerView and solve the problem of get

```
public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {




        private String[] listOfItems;

    public MyListAdapter(String[] listOfItems){
        this.listOfItems = listOfItems;

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        Boolean attachViewImmediatelyToParent = false;
        View singleItemLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,attachViewImmediatelyToParent);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(singleItemLayout);


        return myViewHolder;
    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textShow.setText(listOfItems[position]);
        holder.textShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

Resolve the problem of get in Toast
                Toast.makeText(holder.textShow.getContext(), "you pressed the " + listOfItems.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()+" item"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
Resolve the problem of getting in Toast
            }
        });



    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  listOfItems.length;
    }




    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textShow;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textShow = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvphrase);
        }
    }




}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListofItem` is an `Array` not a `List` in Java.

You should use:

```
listOfItems[holder.getLayoutPosition()];
```

And you should check if the index of the item you are trying to access at `` is not out of bounds:

```
if (holder.getLayoutPosition() < listOfItems.length) {
    listOfItems[holder.getLayoutPosition()];
}
else {
    Log.d("TAG", "Error: index out of bounds");
}
```

To access members in Java:

- For an [Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) : `your_array[index]`
- For a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)  : `your_list.get(index)`

Best

Comment: You're welcome. If that answer to your question, mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, there are two problems:

`Toast.makeText(holder.textShow.getContext(), "you pressed the " + listOfItems.get(holder.getLayoutPosition()+" item"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

1) You have typo error: concatenation `+ "item"` should be **after** closing bracket `)`

2) `listOfItems` is array, not list, so use should use `[]` syntax.

So, proper line is
`Toast.makeText(holder.textShow.getContext(), "you pressed the " + listOfItems[holder.getAdapterPosition()]+" item", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

**UPDATE** P.S.

As well, it's better use `getAdapterPosition()` and not `getLayoutPosition()` inside listeners